# tabs component - javascript not defined error

Tags: javascript

Hello I dont understand why my tabs component is not working.
Do you see something wrong?

This is the error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: openService is not defined

```
function openService(evt, serviceName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("block-services");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("li-services");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(serviceName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

Comment: where are you calling this function?

Comment: make sure that you have this function in scope wherever you are calling it.